# Confused in Big Theta Notation - Asymptotic Notation

Tags: algorithm, asymptotic-complexity, big-o

I am trying to understand the Big Theta notation and came across an example :

[image]

I know we have to find two constants c1 and c2 for this notation such that c1*g(n)<= f(n) <= c2*g(n). My question is how they found out values for these two constants ? Can there be only one specific value for c1 = 1/5 and c2=1 or they can vary ? If yes why only n^2/5 and n^2 and how to determine these values ?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple possible values for *c<sub>1</sub>* and *c<sub>2</sub>*. For example, *c<sub>1</sub>* = 1/6, *c<sub>2</sub>* = 2 and *n<sub>0</sub>* = 1 would work as well. As long as you can establish some pair *c<sub>1</sub>*, *c<sub>2</sub>* of constant multiples of *n<sup>2</sup>* as yielding asymptotic bounds, you prove that the function is *Ɵ(n<sup>2</sup>)*.

Answer (score 1):

In order to prove a particular function *f(n)* is big-theta of another function *g(n)*, you only need to find that there is **a** pair of constants *(c1, c2)* that satisfies the inequality *c1 g(n) ≤ f(n) ≤ c2 g(n)* for all sufficiently large *n*. Note that the pair *(c1, c2)* is **not** unique, for example, it is perfectly valid to prove the big-theta bound by using the following inequality instead:

[image]

Comment: So is it perfectly valid if we say n^2/7 <= f(n) <= n^4 ?

Comment: Yes, but in this case, you have proved f(n) = Ω(n^2) and f(n) = O(n^4), which does not give you a tight bound (i.e. big-theta Θ). f(n) = Θ(g(n)) is equivalent to f(n) = Ω(g(n)) **and** f(n) = O(g(n))

Comment: Oh yes got it. So in order to get the tight upper bound we must keep the order same right ?

Comment: You are right, the *same* function must appear at both the left-hand side and the right-hand side of the inequalities